# didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithError occuring in iphone app

Tags: iphone, keychain, ios-provisioning

I installed app on device on vmware-mac. The program runs successfully.

When I installed app on real Mac Machine, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithError occurs.

What's the problem?

I used right provisioning profile and keychain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NSLog the error that is provided in the didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithError: method.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of various reason (Error code - 404,500 etc) , can you put some log in that function

NSLog(@"error description %@",[error description]);

It will give you exact error which you can google , or let me know if you need any further help on this.